# How to map URLs to views in django?

Tags: python, django

**Goal:**

```
127.0.0.1:8000/about
```

Should give:

welcome to to about us page

```
127.0.0.1:8000/contact
```

Should give:

welcome to contact page

Problem:

Both are giving "page not found at /"

This error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bld8K.jpg

This is my folder structure:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6u4Dq.jpg

This is my main project "taskmate"'s urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin

from django.urls import path, include



urlpatterns = [

    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

    path('task/',include('todolist_app.urls')),

    path('todolist/',include('todolist_app.urls')),        

       
    ]
```

**And for todolist_app, these are my details:**

**Urls.py:**

```
from django.urls import path

from todolist_app import views

#from . import views    



urlpatterns = [

    path('', views.todolist),

    path('contact', views.contact,name='contact'),

    path('about', views.about, name="about"), #the path can be anything.

]
```

**Views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from django.http import HttpResponse



# Create your views here.

def todolist(request):

    context={'welcome_text':"welcome to todo list app"}

    return render(request, 'html/todolist.html',context)



def contact(request):

    context={'welcome_text':"welcome to contact page"}

    return render(request, 'html/contact.html',context)



def about(request):

    context={'welcome_text':"welcome to to about us page"}

    return render(request, 'html/about.html',context)
```

I'm suspecting that the problem is in my main project urls.py as I've not included any details about contact and about URLs there. So, I did this there.

```
from django.contrib import admin

from django.urls import path, include



urlpatterns = [   


    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

    path('task/',include('todolist_app.urls')),

    path('todolist/',include('todolist_app.urls')),

    path('about/',include('todolist_app.urls')), 




    

]
```

The website runs but the goal isn't achieved. Which is obvious because about/ is getting mapped to same URL like todolist/

It shows what the URLs

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/task/
```

And

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/todolist/
```

were Showing instead of what it should be showing.

Now, I think I need to fix the todolist_app urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from todolist_app import views

#from . import views





urlpatterns = [

    path('', views.todolist),

    path('contact', views.contact,name='contact'),

    path('about', views.about, name="about"), #the path can be anything.

]
```

I'm not sure how to fix that. The first thing that I don't understand there is

```
    path('', views.todolist),
```

should mean any urls 127.0.0.1:8000/ should be giving "welcome to todolist app", but only 127.0.0.1:8000/todolist gives it.

And the views mapping for "contact" and "about" are clearly not working.

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: When you include another url config the path is prefixed to all included paths, why are you including the todolist url config multiple times? Does the the url `127.0.0.1:8000/todolist/about` give you the expected output for the about page?

Comment: yes it does. How? I need to look at it.

Comment: If you want your todo list app urls to start at the site root include it just **once** with an empty string for the path - `path('', include('todolist_app.urls')),`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to achieve your goal, change the projec's url file as:

```
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

    path('task/',include('todolist_app.urls')),

    path('',include('todolist_app.urls')), # change as this
```

Then you can get the following things:

`127.0.0.1:8000/about` showing `"welcome to about page"`

`127.0.0.1:8000/contact` showing `"welcome to contact page"`

`127.0.0.1:8000/` showing `"welcome to todolist app page"`

The problem here was in project url file when you add `path('todolist/',include('todolist_app.urls'))`, every urls in the `todolist` app will be prefixed with the given string in project url file.

You can refer [Django - URL Mapping](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/django/django_url_mapping.htm) for more.

Answer (score 0):

**Add a slash after your route:**

```
from django.urls import path

from todolist_app import views

urlpatterns = [

    path('', views.todolist),

    path('contact/', views.contact,name='contact'),

    path('about/', views.about, name='about'), #the path can be anything.

]
```